# Unhandled exception thrown using Lucene.NET in an Azure Worker Role

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, lucene.net, azure-worker-roles

I am trying to create an Azure worker role that indexes docs in Lucene.NET.

However, when I create an `IndexWriter`, it fails with the following exception:

```
System.ExecutionEngineException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException'
         occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

If I build the project as an `.exe`, things work fine - no exception is thrown. I am using .NET Framework 4.0.

My code:

```
var cloudAccount = CloudStorageAccount.FromConfigurationSetting("LuceneBlobStorage");
var cacheDirectory = new RAMDirectory();
var azureDirectory = new AzureDirectory(
                                cloudAccount,"SnowballIndex", cacheDirectory);
var analyzer = new SnowballAnalyzer("English");

// !-- Exception thrown after this call
this.indexWriter = new IndexWriter(
             azureDirectory, analyzer, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
```

Any ideas would be appreciated. I searched online and found nothing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested with my worker Role with exact code (just using Standard Analyzer and the worker role DLL was created without any problem. Will you please try to isolate if this could be an issue with using custom analyzer? Also by chance, do you have .net 4.5 installed in the same machine?

If you could provide your worker role project, i would love to take a look and see what could be issue.

**Edited 06/28/2012**

In my SDK 1.6 based worker role, I just install **Lucene.Net.Store.Azure** package and then added the following code in OnStart() functions and there is no error:

```
StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey creds = new StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey(_azure_storage_name_, _azure_storage_key);
CloudStorageAccount cloudAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(creds, true);
Lucene.Net.Util.Version version = Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29;
var cacheDirectory = new RAMDirectory();
IndexWriter indexWriter = null;
AzureDirectory azureDirectory = new AzureDirectory(cloudAccount, "SnowballIndex", cacheDirectory);
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29);
indexWriter = new IndexWriter(azureDirectory, analyzer, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
```

I think your issue could be machine specific as there is no error and the worker role runs fine.

Comment: Thanks for your help @AvkashChauhan. A few things: 1. I don't have .Net 4.5 installed on my machine. 2. I literally created an empty Azure worker role project via VS2K10 with the _v1.6 SDK_. 3. I've set the Azure version to `Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29`. 4. I switched the analyzer from `Snowball` to `Standard` but still the same problem. In my `Run()` method, I have the above code inline. Not doing anything fancy. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: I have added my code which does not show any error in worker role, please have a look.

Comment: @AvkashChahan - apologize for the delay. I am still getting this error when running in the emulator. Has this run successfully for you under the **emulator** or in **Azure** itself?

Answer (score 0):

Given that blob container names should be in lower case http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd135715.aspx.

Try changing the catalog/index name from “"SnowballIndex" to something like "snowball-index".

Comment: Thanks @Lucifure. I did change to all lower case. Still the same issue.